# How to evaluate set inclusion tests using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I want to eval expressions to check for truthiness.

The user is giving me expressions in the form of

```
x == y || a == (c + 3)
```

or

```
y >= 4
```

I would just use eval with:

```
expression.replace(/[^|()\d\+-><=!&]/g, '');
eval(expression);
```

Now the user wants to give me set inclusion expressions like:

```
5 ∈ y || 3 ∉ y
```

Where `y` is an array. What's the best safe way to handle that?

Edit: Thanks for your help, reading over the answers it's hard to decide which one to pick / which one is better.

Comment: `safe way` ... Where does it run? Client or server?

Comment: @JonasWilms runs web workers and node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the inclusion yourself without `eval`, replace the inclusion tests with either `true` or `false`. To achieve that you should have access to the sets by their name, you can group them into an object `sets` where the keys are names and the values are the sets themselves (see example bellow):

**Inclusion test:**

```
var newString = string.replace(/(\S+)\s*∈\s*(\S+)/g, function(match, item, set) {
    var theActualSet = ...;                  // get the actual set using 'set'
    return theActualSet.includes(+item);
});
```

**Exclusion test:**

```
var newString = string.replace(/(\S+)\s*∉\s*(\S+)/g, function(match, item, set) {
    var theActualSet = ...;                  // get the actual set using 'set'
    return !theActualSet.includes(+item);
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var sets = {
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};

var string = "5 ∈ y || 3 ∉ y";

var newString = string.replace(/(\S+)\s*∈\s*(\S+)/g, function(match, item, set) {
    var theActualSet = sets[set];
    return theActualSet && theActualSet.includes(+item);
});

newString = newString.replace(/(\S+)\s*∉\s*(\S+)/g, function(match, item, set) {
    var theActualSet = sets[set];
    return theActualSet && !theActualSet.includes(+item);
});

console.log("The original string: '" + string + "'");
console.log("The result string: '" + newString + "'");
console.log("The result: " + eval(newString));
```

Now that will be easy to evaluate without any concerns, just remove anything other than `|()\d\+-><=!&` and the literals `true` and `false` and use `eval` to get the result of the evaluation.

**Note:** You can use `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false` to make the removal of the unwanted characters easier: `replace(/[^|()\d\+-><=!&]/g, '')`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if I make the expression more complex: `var string = "(5 ∈ y || 3 ∉ y) && (3 ∈ y || 7 ∉ y)";`

Comment: @Harry That's because `\S+` matches the parentheses too. If you have only numbers and letters, you should change the regex to: `/(\w+)\s*∈\s*(\w+)/g`

Answer (score 1):

Its actually quite hard to replace `a E b` with `b.includes(a)` as you have to take care of operator predescendence. Therefore the only way seems to be to implement your own parser:

```
 const diad = (char, operation) => input =>  {
   // If the operator doesnt exist, don't evaluate
   if(!input.includes(char))
     return input;
   return input.split(char)
     .map(evaluate) // deep first
     .reduce(operation); // left to right
 };

 const bracketsFirst = input => {
   const opening = input.lastIndexOf("("); // the most inner one
   const closing = input.indexOf(")", opening);

   if(opening === -1 || closing === -1) // no brackets, don't evaluate here
     return input;

   const before = input.slice(0, opening);
   const after = input.slice(closing + 1);
   const middle = input.slice(opening + 1, closing);

   return before + evaluate(middle) + after; // just evaluate the thing in the brackets 
};

 let context = {};
 const evaluate = input => [
   bracketsFirst,
   // Boolean algebra
   diad("||", (a, b) => a || b), // lowest operator predescendence
   diad("&&", (a, b) => a && b),
   // Comparison:
   diad("==", (a, b) => a === b),
   diad("!=", (a, b) => a != b),
   diad("<=", (a, b) => a <= b),
   diad(">=", (a, b) => a >= b),
   diad("<", (a, b) => a < b),
   diad(">", (a, b) => a > b),
   // Math:
   diad("+", (a, b) => a + b),
   diad("-", (a, b) => a - b),
   diad("*", (a, b) => a * b),
   diad("/", (a, b) => a / b),
   // The custom operator:
   diad("E", (a, b) => b.includes(a)),
   // Booleans
   a => a.trim() === "true" ? true : a,
   a => a.trim() === "false" ? false : a,
   // Number literals & Identifiers
   a => +a || context[a.trim()] || a,
   a => { throw Error("Unknown:" + a) }
 ].reduce((out, fn) => typeof out === "string" ? fn(out) : out, input);
```

So you can do:

```
 context.a = [1,2,3];
 context.one = 1;
 evaluate("1 E a || 5 E a"); // false
 evaluate("one == 1(5 - 5) - 9"); // true :)
```

[Try it!](http://jsbin.com/fanadiguwi/edit?console)

Comment: Does this respect operator precedence? Also by looking at some of OP's examples, it will be quite hard to evaluate them with a custom parser.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Mathematical expression parsers are fairly simple, even if you don't use any of the libraries available (which make it almost trivial). I mean, it's something you do in college as a small part of a single class.

Comment: @ibrahim yes it will (mostly), and yes a custom parser is complicated but a lot of regexes will get complicated too...

Comment: I've just noticed: the splitting by the operator causes problems if there is more than one instance of the operator: `"5 == 6 || 5 == 2 || 6 == 6"` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @ibrahim yup, fixed.